# Should I use a different object to lock for each property?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a class and its properties; the access to these properties is **very frequently** done by different threads.

It is more efficient use the same object (for the lock statement) for each property?

```
private readonly object padlock = new object();

private string name;
private int age;

public string Name
{
   get
   {
      lock(padlock)
         return name;
   }

   set
   {
      lock(padlock)
         name = value;
   }
}

public int Age
{
   get
   {
      lock(padlock)
         return age;
   }

   set
   {
      lock(padlock)
         age = value;
   }
}
```

Or to use a different object for each property?

```
private readonly object padlockName = new object();
private readonly object padlockAge = new object();

private string name;
private int age;

public string Name
{
   get
   {
      lock(padlockName)
         return name;
   }

   set
   {
      lock(padlockName)
         name = value;
   }
}

public int Age
{
   get
   {
      lock(padlockAge)
         return age;
   }

   set
   {
      lock(padlockAge)
         age = value;
   }
}
```

The second version makes any sense?

Comment: It depends - Are your properties linked together, that they can't be read and changed at the same time?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek No, but the problem is that if one thread is reading/writing the Name property another thread have to wait before to read/write the Age property. Is this wait time (due to the use of the same object) relatively high or is better to use the same object anyway?

Comment: @LightStriker a) if the type is a value type, then the lock is worthless, you get a new `object` every time due to boxing b) you break encapsulation, as that same object (in the case of reference types like `string`) is going to be passed out of the class, someone can lock on that and then cause deadlocks in your code.

Comment: @Nick We can't answer that question, only you can.  It's based strongly on how the class is used.  Even you would have a hard time trying to figure it out conceptually.  The only practical method is to code both and profile the results.

Comment: @Servy unfortunately I think you're right..

Comment: @casperOne so, have I to remove the lock for all value type properties? And how have I to manage the lock statement when I return a reference?

Comment: Not sure why you are locking these - int and string (among other types) will not get corrupted through reads/writes from different threads.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278.aspx

Comment: No, @Light was suggesting that you use the value itself instead of a separate padlock object.  That is always going to fail.

Answer (score 4):

I hesitate to even answer the question you've asked, because I doubt that either of these locking patterns will ensure correctness in your application. They don't ensure that the object as a whole is kept in a consistent state - they just ensure that individual properties are not updated concurrently. To put it another way, you've implemented atomic reads and writes in a roundabout way.

For example, say you had an operation that would increment `Age`. If two different threads did that at once, the final result could be (Age + 1) or (Age + 2).

You should most likely remove locking from within the object, and have callers deal with concurrency issues as appropriate. One easy solution is to lock the entire object for the duration of their interaction with it. eg:

```
lock(myObj){
  myObj.Age++;
  myObj.Name = "Bill";
}
```

**Update**

To expand on my middle paragraph, the reason that running `Age++` on two different threads could give different results is because the `++` operator is not atomic. It is roughly equivalent to this.

```
int temp = Age;
temp = temp + 1;
Age = temp;
```

If two threads ran the same thing, it could execute in order like this (for clarity I've changed names of the temp variables):

```
int temp1 = Age; //thread 1
int temp2 = Age; //thread 2
temp1 = temp1 + 1;  //thread 1
temp2 = temp2 + 1; //thread 2
Age = temp1; //thread 1
Age = temp2; //thread 2
```

The purpose of locking is to ensure that one thread runs the entire read-increment-write sequence before the other thread does. But your locking scheme doesn't do that.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is very important. +1

Comment: I do not understand. If 2 different threads incement Age the final result will be Age + 2: what is strange in this result if it is what I want? And lock every time myOby does not increase performance. Can you elaborate better?

Answer (score 0):

Note, this is highly dependent on how your object is accessed.  The ultimate answer will be determined by measuring your performance in *your* environment and acting on that as well as the needs specific to *your* domain (although it seems like your concern here is corrupting the variables used to back the properties, not about accessing clusters of properties at the same time).

That said you have to balance out the following:

- If you have one object to lock access to *all* the properties on the object, multiple threads accessing different properties will wait on each other to complete.
- If you have one object *per property*, then accessing different properties will not cause locks to be waiting.

However, I'd say in this case it's moot as it seems like you're more worried about corruption of the values here.

[Assignments and reads on a vast majority of types (excluding multi-field value types) are atomic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278.aspx), meaning you won't corrupt them.

That said, in the example above, where you have a read and write of a property of type `string` (a reference type) and an `int`, those operations are atomic and cannot be corrupted by reads/writes from multiple threads.